# Android Marshmallow - How to grant dangerous permissions to Platform Signed Application

Tags: android

I am working on an application that will be signed with the platform signature. I want to enable all the permissions by default for this application. The Device Administrator privilege should also be enabled for this application. Is there a way we can do this?

Comment: Is the app being built with the platform, or built separately and just signed with the platform keys?

Comment: the app is built separately and signed with the platform keys

Comment: You would have to build the app with a shared user ID set in the manifest to one of the privileged user IDs (such as android.uid.system or android.uid.shell).

Comment: @LarrySchiefer Thanks for your help. We have added shared user id android.uid.system. Now the Permissions section reads "No Permissions Requested". Is this the expected behaviour? Also, Device Admin is not enabled by default, anything we can do to enable it?

Comment: I don't know that you can have a default device admin app without modifying the settings app, system properties or the framework. You should also be able to check what permissions have been granted (not just requested).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't enable all of them by default.
You need to add them one by one in your Manifest depending on what do you need in your app.

For example INSTALL_PACKAGES is a permission that requires your app to be installed with platform signature.